# Regarding Xamarin Developement with visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

- We are new to xamarin developement, i have installed complete package for visual studio regarding it and started with the trial environment. now i need to install android framework with version 4.0 and Api 19 as it only provide 2.3 and 3.1.
- I also want to know about that how much space will be needed to install the package of version 4.3 or higher. Because i have already faced low disk space issue more than one time during the installation., Its using already 10gb of space in my drive so just wondering it requires more than 10 gb?
- Another thing i also want to know that, is backward compatibility supported on xamarin visual studio. so if i am implementing the application in version 2.3 then is it supported to version 2.3+(Higher)?

Thanks,
Ankit Sanghvi

Comment: Backward compatibility would be that you develop for version 4.3 for instance and then assume that it will also be working on older (Android) versions. So I think you are rather talking about forward compatibility which cannot be guaranteed. I guess if no API changes in the future Android release, you would be able to run the old app, but some testing will be definitely needed to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

- In visual studio go to "Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager..." and install version that you want.
- It won't take you more then 10gb, each version should take around 100mb
- Xamarin is backward compatible with versions same as Java. Look at Android project settings where you can set: "Compile time Android version", "Minimum Android to target" and "Target Android version".